# Printing Index of Object

Tags: c#

I have created an object array as such:

```
object[,] Values = new object[17, 5];

Layer1[0, 0] = neuron1;
Layer1[1, 0] = neuron1;
Layer1[2, 0] = neuron2;
```

etc.

I have written a function to loop through the object array which is:

```
static void Loop_Through_Layer(object[,] Layer1)
{
    //Loop through objects in array
    foreach (object element in Layer1)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            //Loop through objects in array
            foreach (object index in Layer1)
            {
                if (index != null)
                {
                    //Need to print indexes of values
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am attempting to do it so print the location of every value within the object array through using the for loop but I am unsure how to reference these coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with `foreach` since it "flattens" the array - you could use two plain `for` loops instead:

```
//Loop through objects in array
for(int i = 0; i < Layer1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Layer1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var element = Layer1[i,j];
        if (element != null)
        {
             //Need to print indexes of values
             Console.WriteLine("Layer1[{0},{1}] = {2}", i, j, element);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the bounds and a `for` loop to get the values:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Layer1.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Layer1.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        //
        // You have position x and y here.
        //
        Console.WriteLine("At x '{0}' and y '{1}' you have this value '{2}'", x, y, Layer1[x, y]);
    }
}
```